# Why isn't my jQuery if/else statement working?

Tags: javascript

In an attempt to brush up on my jQuery, I'm trying to make a functional tic-tac-toe game. I've managed to run into a problem pretty early on.

Here is a jsFiddle (you may have to change the width to get the right board layout):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xcg22twj/1/

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var board = $('.board');
    subtitle = $('.subtitle');
    gamespace = $('.gamespace');
    a1 = $('.a1');
    a2 = $('.a2');
    a3 = $('.a3');
    b1 = $('.b1');
    b2 = $('.b2');
    b3 = $('.b3');
    c1 = $('.c1');
    c2 = $('.c2');
    c3 = $('.c3');
    piece = $('.piece');
    pieceX = $('.pieceX');
    pieceO = $('.pieceO');
    player1select = true;
    player2select = false;
    player1piece = "";
    player2piece = "";
    gameOver = true;

    if (gameOver == true) {
        $(board).css('display', 'none');

        $(pieceX).click(function () {
            player1piece = "x";
            player2piece = "o";
            $(pieceX).css('display', 'none');
            $(pieceO).css('display', 'none');
            subtitle.html('Player 1 = X | Player 2 = O');
            $(board).css('display', 'inline');
        })

        $(pieceO).click(function () {
            player1piece = "o";
            player2piece = "x";
            $(pieceX).css('display', 'none');
            $(pieceO).css('display', 'none');
            subtitle.html('Player 1 = O | Player 2 = X');
            $(board).css('display', 'inline');
        })

        if (player1piece.length > 0 && player2piece.length > 0) {
            gameOver = false;
        }
    } else {
        $(gamespace).hover(

        function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'tomato');
        }, function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
        });
    }
});
```

Basically, my problem is that I want the gameOver variable to be false until player one selects either X or O. After selection the pieces disappear, the board appears, gameOver is set to false, and the game begins. However, the if/else statement that checks whether gameOver is true or false doesn't seem to be working properly. If it were working, I would be able to hover over each space and it would change to tomato.

Can anyone explain why it's not working that way?

Thank you.

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't work. You didn't add the jQuery library reference.

Comment: You're defining `gameOver` as `true`, then immediately checking whether it's true. Doesn't make much sense, eh? Also, every variable except the first is being initialized in the global namespace. That's bad.

Comment: Also, you're setting it to false within the if condition, but never re-calls your function.

Comment: Fiddle updated with jQuery and TidyUp.

Comment: Hm, really? jsfiddle is working for me. How would I re-call that function then?

Comment: You have plenty of missing semi-colons in your code.

Comment: what are you even trying to accomplish, the if statement isn't doing anything, the elements are being double $(), and you are completely over complicating things, I suggest you read up on how jQuery works before continuing.

Comment: You've already assigned a jQuery object to variable, `pieceX = $('.pieceX');` and then again accessing it as jQuery object!! (`$(pieceX).click(function(){...});`) Seems wrong. It is like writing `$($('.pieceX'))`. Fix your code first.

Comment: Fortunately, jQuery handles that fairly gracefully. It's nowhere near as bad as dbarnes' horrific comma abuse, for example. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here, some of which were mentioned in the comments above. The most problematic may be that your `if` statement needs to be called on some event. It should probably be inside the click functions you've defined.

Comment: Thanks, I'll tinker around with that.

Comment: Also look into defining variables locally and not globally using `var`.

Comment: Progress! Rather than having a discussion in the comments here, please delete this question and ask a new, more specific one when you need help.